# Left side of post edit info (last activity) is cut off in responsive view on mobile

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, last-activity

In the question listing on my mobile responsive view, when a post's edit information (i.e. the last activity on the post) overflows onto a second line, the left side of this information is cut off/obscured.

E.g. on [ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/):

> [image: Edit information for a recent post on ruSO's Meta shows "изменён 20 часов назад Nicolas Chabanovsky (Сотрудник) (Мод) 49.6k", but the last number appears on the second line, with the leftmost end of "изменён" and "49.6k" being cut off]

Comment: I've edited your post to try and clarify what you're asking; please check to make sure I've correctly conveyed your intended meaning.

Comment: @V2Blast thank you very much.

Comment: Is it related [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/editing-a-post-leads-to-a-weird-behavior)? There is a time correlation.