# Editing a post leads to a weird behavior

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, inline-editor

Editing a post with the inline editor for users with 2K+ reputation leads to the following weird behavior:

[image: Animated GIF of the edit process. The user edits, scrolls down, and hits the save edit button. There is a dialog box popping up asking "You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit? And 'Yes' and 'Cancel' options.]

When you edit and save your edit, it asks you if you want to abandon your edits - as if you hadn't changed them. If you select <kbd>Yes</kbd> the edits are saved and the edits are not abandoned.  If you hit <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, the post vanishes until you refresh.

Tested on Chrome on Android and Windows ([bug demo on Android](https://youtu.be/bEVka4_gr-A)).

The issue has been reproduced on most supported browsers across the network.

Comment: Already reported on MSO: [Getting "You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?" when saving an edit](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415234/4642212).

Comment: This has also been reported on Math meta at [Are you sure you want to leave this page?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34470/602049).

Comment: Report at rpg: [Bug when saving edit: I made my post disappear](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11908/62294).

Comment: This only seems to be happening with the 2k+ inline post editor; the separate editor page (`/posts/[post ID]/edit`) seems to be unaffected, as does the 10k+ inline tag editor. As a workaround, users with 2k+ rep can manually browse to the separate editor page either through the revision history or using URL modification.

Comment: Which feels like a pain. Clicking through the entirely bogus and unnecessary warning works well enough :D

Comment: That said, while this is a valid bug report, I'm voting to close this as needs detail/clarity since it doesn't contain much detail as to what the problem is and how to reproduce it (prior to @JourneymanGeek's edit I had no idea what it was without reading comments). While I understand the image size limitation prevents a higher-resolution animated GIF, the post depends on an external source for a clear picture, and users in places where Imgur and/or YouTube are blocked will have no way to tell what it's about. The post should contain a clear text description of the problem and how to reproduce

Comment: See the [extended tag wiki for the bug tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info) for the required details for a bug report.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog eh. This is a *real* problem, possibly not articulated as well it should be. This is one of those situations where rather than not closing for being "perfect" Its worth it for the community to try to, well, sort it out.

Comment: I also had this occur in the non-inline edit while I had a different tab of the same answer that I was editing open where I initially started an inline edit.

Comment: The devs are working on this bug. [Thanks for notifying us, we were able to reproduce it and will try to fix this asap. We'll keep you posted on this question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/getting-you-have-started-editing-this-post-abandon-this-edit-when-saving-an?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment889069_415234)

Comment: I get this behavior on a Mac using Safari. It isn't an intermittent problem, but occurs consistently.

Comment: Got the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 using Chrome 97.0.4692.71

Comment: Cause of the error: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/getting-you-have-started-editing-this-post-abandon-this-edit-when-saving-an?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment889171_415252

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all: thanks a lot to everybody for notifying us about this issue. We have been able to reproduce and fix it. Please do let us know (in a comment to this answer) if you're still encountering any issues with this.

Comment: I just encountered it within the past ten minutes. But that was on a question I first asked yesterday and still had open in my browser, so it may be a refresh fluke.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it @JosiahYoder! My guess that it is because it was still open in your browser, but please ping me if you encounter it ones more. Again: very much appreciate everybody letting us know :).

Comment: If you type in the answer box and wait long enough (*invisible* draft save), then try to navigate away from the page it will ask if you want to leave - that is fine. --- If you delete all the text in the answer box, even discard your answer, so the box is empty it will *still* ask if you wish to leave the page. That is pointless and not the same behavior as a week or two ago.

Comment: ^ [That](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/editing-a-post-leads-to-a-weird-behavior/375068#comment1249519_375068) appears to be fixed now, thanks.